# Did giving 10 reputation for each question upvote (instead of 5) have the desired effect?

Tags: discussion, reputation

In 2019, Stack Exchange started giving [10 reputation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) for every question upvote, instead of 5. Has any study investigated whether the quality or quantity of questions increased after that change?

Comment: I'm not sure how a study could *possibly* calculate that given so many other changes have been made to the question asking experience as well. It also wasn't a stated goal of the change and we didn't expect question quality to improve with that change. Unless you are meant to be referring to the other changes to the experience that shipped around that same time and not explicitly just the reputation reward.

Comment: Regardless of whether it had any impact whatsoever on anything, at best looking at the data would only be useful for potential future changes that *don't* change it back. Staff could certainly look at survey data trends since then to see that it had no impact on user satisfaction, but that certainly wouldn't be grounds to go back... removing rep is a much harder pill to swallow than adding.

Answer (score 10):

Quantity? Not really, there is no visible uptick in asking questions (using Stack Overflow as the most representative site on the network) in the six months that followed the change:

[image: trend of questions posted in 2019-2020 after the change took effect]

You might've noticed a steady increase starting around March, but spring is usually a busier season, and you can see that the number of questions asked normalizes over the course of the summer:

[image: trend of questions posted in 2019-2020 up til September]

---

Quality? Not in the slightest — it wasn't even the [stated goal](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) of the change:

> our goal is to have the question asking process be painless and beneficial for new people and Stack Overflow veterans alike

Let me rephrase that to make clearer what it actually means: "our goal is to make askers *feel good*". This was never about the quality.

If we define "quality question" as a non-closed, non-deleted post with a score higher than 0, graphing them shows that any uptick in the number of such questions posted after the change corresponds to the increase in the total number of questions for the respective period (sorry, the red line is a little off):

[image: trend of quality questions posted in 2019 after the change til May 2020 compared to the trend of total questions posted]

Nor did it have any significant impact on either the "quality" or the quantity of *answers* posted after the change:

[image: trend of quality answers posted in 2019 after the change til May 2020 compared to the trend of total answers posted]

It did not even do anything of note to the voting patterns on questions:

[image: trend of votes (total, upvotes, and downvotes) on questions in 2019 after the change til May 2020]

---

So, to sum up: it was pretty inconsequential, I guess — yay?

Comment: *"Let me rephrase that to make clearer what it actually means: "our goal is to make askers feel good". This was never about the quality."* is that not something that staff can draw data for via the satisfaction surveys that have ran since then?

Comment: @KevinB I suppose they could - after all, it's feelings we are talking about here (although I have a small prediction that for every good feeling this recalc generated it created an annoyed curator/answerer). Just wanted to emphassize that the change was definitely not made in the spirit of promoting quality contributions - and the data seems to support this: if it was of any consequence to the "quantity of quality", we would observe a substantial uptick or dent in the months followinng the change - which did not happen. Even the voting patterns did not change much (which is...

Comment: ...a bit surprising given that many voiced their intent to reevaluate the frequency and criteria with which they would upvote questions as feedback to the recalc)